# Looking for a a rewriteRule solution

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an url rewriting issue.
All the topic urls of my website point at www.mywebsite.com/topic.php?topic=id
I wanted to change those urls to www.mywebsite.com/topic-id.html

I did it with that in an .htaccess file :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^topic-([0-9]+)\.html$ /topic.php?topic=$1
```

Now i would like all urls pointing to /topic.php?topic=id to  be rewritten like topic-id.html, in order to have only one url displayed for users without rewriting all my code. **Is it possible to do that ?**

I tried the [R] flag that way :

```
RewriteRule ^topic-([0-9]+)\.html$ /topic.php?topic=$1 [R]
```

But it's doing the opposite of what i'm looking for, since it converts all urls like ( topic-id.html ) to ( topic.php?topic=id ).

I specify, that i'm not looking for a solution to **"the duplicate content issue"**

Any help would be great, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this , I hop this work for you

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/topic\.php\?id=([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ /topic.php?id=$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/topic\.php\?id=([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+?)(?:\.html)?$ /index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following above your existing rules (bellow the `RewriteEngine on` line):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /topic\.php\?id=(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /topic-%1.html [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to use is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^topic-([^-]*)\.html$ /topic.php?topic=$1 [L]
```